# MariaDB Java Reactive client

Tags: java, mariadb, reactive

Im looking for a java MariaDB reactive client/driver to use with Spring Reactor.

Found some on this internet and they look a bit dubious/are not active anymore and most didnt make it to version 1.x+.

Is there any reliable, mature, truly reactive (Im far from being a reactive expert, but I understood some are just wrappers) client for MariaDB?

Answer (score 1):

You're right, nothing "serious" except this 'io.r2dbc:r2dbc-postgresql:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'.

If you have the possibility to migrate to pg, r2dbc is not a wrapper but a reactive functional support to native SQL DB driver(s).

See https://r2dbc.io for more information about R2DBC

Comment: To the one who had put -1: Where is your answer please ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [jasync-sql](https://github.com/jasync-sql/jasync-sql) which I am working on. It has MySQL support so I guess MariaDB as well though I haven't tested it. So if you encounter any issue it will be great if we can assist.

It works with spring as follows:

```
fun getUsers(req: ServerRequest) =
    ok().body(
           Mono.fromFuture(
               db.connectionPool.sendPreparedStatement("select * from user;"))
                .map { it.rows.orEmpty() }
         )
```

Take a look here for full example: https://github.com/jasync-sql/jasync-sql/blob/master/samples/spring-kotlin/README.md

UPDATE: jasync-sql also supports r2dbc. See example here: https://github.com/jasync-sql/jasync-sql/tree/master/samples/mysql-r2dbc

Comment: Since MySQL itself doesnt support async yet, its not really reactive right? Lets say the MySQL db im connecting to can support 50 connections at the same time, the netty threads wont be waiting but they can only have 50 requests "in the air" at the same time right?

Comment: I don't think that is the main property of being reactive. Anyway this driver is async, means there is no wrapper nor thread per connection as you mentioned. The implementation of mysql itself is less important here IMHO, every server has a limit on connections, and with slaves and proxies mysql can get to a high number of concurrent connections.

Comment: It is an important aspect. Backpressure is the key component to reactive programming, its not just async which leads to runaway resource starvation or blocking.